# Почему я добавляю папку на отслеживание, а она все равно горит красным

Tags: git

Скачал чужой уже готовый репазиторий.
Добавляю папку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю git status оно все равно красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так Permission denied... Вы, небось, `git clone` из под `root` делали?

Comment: всмысле sudo? нет просто набирал

Answer (score 0):

git add ./src

у вас вместо . стоит :

Comment: Все равно тоже самое

Answer (score -1):

У Вас по каким-то причинам нет доступа к служебным файлам репозитория..

Починить права доступа к файлам репозитория/настроек можно так:

```
sudo chown -R $USER .git
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/git
```

Вместо переменной $USER можно писать своё имя пользователя: `ivansinevich`

Comment: А как вообще избавится от этого sudo?

Comment: В смысле избавиться? Почему у вас нет прав доступа к файлу `~/.config/git/attributes`?

Comment: Мне сказали что если использовать sudo, то потом проблем хлебнешь. Я вообще не понимаю что это значит, какое sudo, что там куда

Comment: Тут вместо $User надо свой вписывать я правильно понимаю?

Comment: ivansinevich$ sudo chown -R $ivansinevich .git

Comment: Неправильно, в переменной $USER уже хранится имя пользователя